# How to implement updated code using Gradle that is not the part of dependency yet?

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm using android ui library [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) using gradle like below.

```
dependencies {     
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/red1004g/PagerSlidingTabStrip/commit/2cf61e1ad8c59b631bcd3861c5ee8df51b873ebd) says new functions are added however I can't use it in my project. I've found that I should add updated codes in my project manually but since I'm not familiar with gradle/git I don't know how to to this...

What should I do?

Comment: What are you talking about? You mention one library and show the dependency for another.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Sorry, I edited it

Comment: Just to let you know that is deprecated. The author has not updated that project in `2 years`. The "forked" updated project is here: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip. Why not use the official `TabLayout` from Google:https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thank you for noticing me. I'm trying!